# How to delete second previous class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have navigation menu. If i click another button, it deletes .active from that button and adds it to clicked button. I want to add class "previousButton" only to previous button. My solution gives previous class to all previous button.

```js
$(".btn").first().addClass("active");

$(".btn").focus(function(){
  $(this).siblings("button").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");


  if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).prevAll().addClass("previous");
  }

  $(".previous").last().addClass("previousButton");



  
});
```

```css
.active {color:green};
.previous {color: white};
.previousButton {color: pink};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
          <button class="btn" >1. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">2. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">3. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">4. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">5. Page</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the class to all previous siblings because that's precisely what you're instructing, via `prevAll()`.

Instead you can just add this class in the same line as you remove the `active` class, provided you modify the selector to target specifically the element which currently has `active`, rather than all `button` siblings.

```
$(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active").addClass('previous');
```

Furthermore, your condition is unnecessary since it will always resolve to true:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { //<-- always true - we added the class in the previous line
```

Putting it all together:

```
$(".btn").focus(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active").addClass('previous');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".previous").last().addClass("previousButton");
});
```

Or to reduce the code even further, the first and second lines inside the callback can be merged:

```
$(this).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active").addClass('previous');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know jQuery, I'd propose an easy JavaScript solution. (you could easily translate it since the logic is quiet simple).

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (let i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // clear all previous buttons
    const prevButton = document.getElementsByClassName('previous')[0];
    
    if (prevButton) prevButton.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
  
    // add previous class to active button
    document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].setAttribute('class', 'btn previous');
    
    // add active class to current clicked button
    event.target.setAttribute('class', 'btn active');
  });
};
```

```css
.active { color:green; } 
.previous { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
          <button class="btn active">1. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">2. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">3. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">4. Page</button>
          <button class="btn">5. Page</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'in a weird way'. isn't this what you desired? @Zyonix

Comment: If i go from 5. to 4. red previous is on the next button.

Comment: what did you mean by previous button? I am assuming the button clicked before the active button is going to be the previous button. Something like 1->5(previous)->4(active). @Zyonix